# How to read binary file of an image uploaded at input file type?

Tags: php, file, curl, input, binaryfiles

I have an input (id = fileFaq / type="file"), how can i get the binary file of the image uploaded?

I have this array, which will be send (POST) via PHP cURL:

[image: ARRAY]

And i really think i need to add the binary file at array['file'], so the image can be send correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you want...

```
$binary = file_get_contents($_FILES['UPLOADEDFILENAME']['tmp_name']);
```

Not quite sure about how to send the data via curl as (from my knowledge anyway) it depends on the receiving end.